# Is there any computation that can *only* be carried out combining two or more parallel processes?

Tags: multiprocessing

An analogy: two people (say) are able to transport a sofa, none of them alone can. Im am wondering if such thing may happen in multiprocessing.

Comment: No, unless you claim a parallel process can't be carried out without doing parallel processing by definition of the words, but that's circular.

Comment: Well, thanks @ChrisDodd, but this doesn't appear as a valid answer to me; couldn't it happen that two things need to be done at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.

Any system that is [Turing Complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) can emulate any other system(including multi-threading and parallel tasks). It may be slower than native execution, but it can always be done.

Some issues such as concurrency and synchronization issues may not occur(they are not deterministic on multiprocessor machines).